# Passing a PHP array into javascript and appending each of the array values into my dropdown options

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to pass an array consisting of values fetched from a table column and appending each of the values in my dropdown menu in html page. This is my code:

```
function get_code(){
    $.ajax({
            url : 'index_backend.php',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {"input":"code"},
            success : function(response) {
                alert(response); //["1000001","1000002","1000003"]
                var select = document.getElementById("colony_code");
                for(var i=0; i<response.length; i++){
                    var opt = response[i];
                    var el = document.createElement("option");
                    el.textContent = opt;
                    el.value = opt;
                    select.appendChild(el); //dropdown shows [, ", 1,... like this
                }
            },
            complete: function(){
            }
    });
}
```

When I try to append the values one by one into my dropdown options, it splits each of the values by their initial characters. How do I fix this?

Comment: Try adding dataType: "json" to your $.ajax settings, it looks like jQuery is evaluating your response as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `response` value is an **array**, your code to display the values will work correctly:

```js
var response = ["1000001", "1000002", "1000003"]
var select = document.getElementById("colony_code");
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
  var opt = response[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = opt;
  el.value = opt;
  select.appendChild(el);
}
```

```html
<select id="colony_code"></select>
```

As such, I have to assume that `response` is actually a **string representation** of `'["1000001","1000002","1000003"]'`

It would be best to correct the data itself, by explicitly stating that it is JSON data, by adding `datatype: 'json'` to the `$.ajax()`. This can be reinforced on the PHP side with `header('Content-Type: application/json')`.

You *could* also correct it on the client by explicitly parsing it. The easiest way would be using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). This can be seen in the following:

```js
var response = '["1000001", "1000002", "1000003"]';
var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
var select = document.getElementById("colony_code");
for (var i = 0; i < parsedResponse.length; i++) {
  var opt = parsedResponse[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = opt;
  el.value = opt;
  select.appendChild(el);
}
```

```html
<select id="colony_code"></select>
```